# Command failed: java -jar

Tags: javascript, java, electron, electron-builder

I am using the package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/easy-pdf-merge

To merge several PDF files, and it works fine when run from NodeJS.
However when I pack it through Electron-builder I get the following error "Command failed: java -jar" I am guessing it has something to do with Electron-Builder putting node modules into the "app.asar".

I have downloaded Java and added to Path (which means it works fine from CMD)

```
var merge = require('easy-pdf-merge');

merge(filePaths, 'merged.pdf', function (err) {

    if (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    }

    resolve('ok');
});
```

I am not very skilled in either Java or Electron-Builder so any input would be helpful

EDIT:
I have updated code with closing bracket and removed error with opening jar file.

Comment: Also there is an error here `console.log('Error: ' + err` . There is no closing bracket

Comment: The "Unable to access jarfile" is the cause of the problem. The `java -jar` command attempts to access that jarfile but cannot do so. Try to resolve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting the node module in the app.asar.unpacked folder by modifying package.json with:

```
  "build": {
    "asar": true,
    "asarUnpack": [
      "node_modules/easy-pdf-merge/**/*"
    ]
  },
```

Afterwards I used the following to reference the node module:

```
var merge = require(path.join(__dirname, '/../../app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/easy-pdf-merge'));
```